# Using XML to populate a JComboBox - something missing

Tags: java, xml, swing, jcombobox

it's me again.
I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<components>
    <resources>
        <resource id="House">
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
            <maxUsage>float</maxUsage>
            <minUsage>float</minUsage>
            <averageUsage>float</averageUsage>
        </resource>
        <resource id="Commerce">
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
            <maxUsage>float</maxUsage>
            <minUsage>float</minUsage>
            <averageUsage>float</averageUsage>
        </resource>
        <resource id="Industry">
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
            <maxUsage>float</maxUsage>
            <minUsage>float</minUsage>
            <averageUsage>float</averageUsage>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <agregatorsType1>
        <agregator1 id="CSP">
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
        </agregator1>
        <agregator1 id="Microgrid">     
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
        </agregator1>
    </agregatorsType1>
    <soagregatorsType0>
        <agregator0 id="VPP">
            <id>int</id>
            <type>string</type>
        </agregator0>
    </agregatorsType0>
</components>
```

and I want to populate a JComboBox with the id's of each Resource (House, Commerce and Industry).

I have the following method:

```
public static String[] readResourcesXML(String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception {


//Gets XML
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document documento = docBuilder.parse(fileName);

//Searches all text 
documento.getDocumentElement().normalize();

//Gets elements from xml 
Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();
NodeList listaResources = raiz.getElementsByTagName("resources");

//Search all resources 
int tam = listaResources.getLength();
String[] vecResources = new String[tam];

for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    Element elem = (Element) listaResources.item(i);           
    vecResources[i] =  elem.getAttribute("/resource/@id");
}
    //returns an array with all the id's of the resources
    return vecResources;
}
```

NOTE: The String fileName has the following value: "src\configs\features.xml"

The problem is, the JComboBox is always empty. What am I missing?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Element#getAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) retrieves attributes directly from `Elements` rather than from the nested elements. You need to iterate over `resource` instead:

```
NodeList listaResources = raiz.getElementsByTagName("resource");

int tam = listaResources.getLength();
String[] vecResources = new String[tam];

for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
   Element elem = (Element) listaResources.item(i);      
   System.out.println(elem);
   vecResources[i] =  elem.getAttribute("id"); // change to id
}
```

Comment: btw, if I want to print the sub-elements?
id
type
maxUsage
etc
What do I need to do?

Comment: You would need to iterate down through those elements using `getElementsByTagName` similar to what you have done already

Comment: is there any other way?
because with `getElementsByTagName` I need to write the name of the tag and the XML file is going to be changed. someone can just add a sub-element to a House.

Comment: This way will allow for elements to be added. You will ofc have to update your code if you want to read in any new elements

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it without having to update the code. Do you happen to know any?

Comment: It should be doable with `getNextSibling` - will leave the implementation as an excercise ;))